# Mulesoft Transform Message Error: "There are some error in the current classpath"

Tags: mule

New to working with MuleSoft, and I am getting an error "There are some error in the current classpath" when adding in a Transform Message into the Message Flow. I have just finished setting up Anypoint Studio, so this might be a configuration step I have missed somewhere.

[DW Script Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5JQR.png)
[Payload (default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUtpw.png)

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue and i follow below mentioned steps,
Go to the project **Right Click** > **Mule** > **Update Project Dependencies**

**Note:- Before performing above steps make sure, you are connected with internet.**

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This option is actually dimmed out on my project

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue this morning and after a lot of playing around have finally managed to get it working. What did the trick in the end was to go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path, click on the Mule Server 3.7.2 EE entry, hit Edit, reselect the same version of the server runtime, click Finish, click Ok. This in itself didn't seem to make any difference, but then I restarted Anypoint Studio and everything was now working correctly.

I have done some digging, and found the following difference in the projects *.classpath* file:

before:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="MULE_RUNTIME"/>
```

after:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="MULE_RUNTIME/org.mule.tooling.server.3.7.2.ee"/>
```

Hopefully this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - hasn't worked for me even though the class file does reflect the same change.

Comment: In my case I had to update the path for the Maven repository (using Maven).  Right-mouse click project name in Package Explorer.  Under Java Build Path I corrected the path for M2_REPO.

Comment: This helped me, my issue is that i did a re-install on a new PC and copied over my projects, but I changed my repo structure. So my external JAR references were invalid. Once I edited them and set them to their actual path, the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project --> go to the properties --> select the required java version and any domain projects --> remove any un-referenced java version/domain from Java build path.

Answer (score 0):

Check once if MAVEN_HOME is added as environment variable and %MAVEN_HOME%\bin is added to path variable in environment variables. 
Also try deleting the .mule file created in the workspace and then try restarting Anypoint Studio. After that in command prompt traverse till your project folder and run `mvn clean install` command.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, I navigated to project->properties->Java Buildpath. There are some jar file dependencies that are not pointing to correct file locations. I updated them and the error dissappeared.